# Making a simple FreeBSD package with "make package"

Tags: makefile, freebsd, ports

This is sort of a Hello World situation for FreeBSD ports.

I'm trying to make a FreeBSD .tbz file for a small webapp I made.  The project consists of a single foo.war file which I've zipped into foo.tgz.  I put this .tgz in /usr/ports/distfiles.  Then in /usr/ports/textproc/foo I made the files Makefile, distinfo, pkg-descr, and pkg-plist.  I'd like to create the tbz by running "make package."  When I run make package, my Makefile produces errors.  I'm using an adapted Makefile from another port, and I don't fundamentally understand what a simple Makefile needs.  Here is what I have in my Makefile:

```
8 PORTNAME=>  foo
9 PORTVERSION=>   1.0
10 CATEGORIES=>textproc java
11 MASTER_SITES=>  ftp://freefall.cdrom.com/pub/FreeBSD/LOCAL_PORTS/
12 MASTER_SITE_SUBDIR=>
13 EXTRACT_SUFX=>  .tgz
14
15 MAINTAINER=>...
16 COMMENT=>   ...
17
18 LICENSE=>   AL2
19 JAVA_VERSION=>  1.5+
20 NO_BUILD=>  yes
21 PLIST_SUB+=>PORTVERSION="${PORTVERSION}"
22 USE_JAVA=>  yes
23 PORTEXAMPLES=>  *
24
25 do-install:
26 >   cd ${WRKSRC}/dist && ${COPYTREE_SHARE} \* ${JAVAJARDIR}
27 .if !defined(NOPORTEXAMPLES)
28 >   ${MKDIR} ${EXAMPLESDIR}
29 >   cd ${WRKSRC}/example && ${COPYTREE_SHARE} \* ${EXAMPLESDIR}
30 .endif
31
32 .include <bsd.port.mk>
```

The do-install block is copied from another file, and that is where I'm seeing errors:

```
"Makefile", line 26: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 28: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 29: Missing dependency operator
```

What do I need to change in my Makefile?  Or any advice for creating a tbz out of a single file on FreeBSD?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm currently also getting the following error and having trouble understanding it: "/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 4370: warning: duplicate script for target "foo._usr_local" ignored.

Comment: Far starters, what version of Make are you using? (If you're not sure, try `make -v`.)

Comment: Where did you get all that '>' signs?

Comment: The > signs are tab characters

Comment: @Beta I tried make -v, but I see the same errors.

Comment: I did which make and it said /usr/bin/make.  I did man make and the title is MAKE(1) FreeBSD General Commands Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you really do have tab characters.  That error usually indicates a line with spaces where there should be tabs.